# \bibnamedelima unavailable in encoding T1

Tags: xetex, biber

Updated question: I am using xelatex / biber on Mac OS X 10.8.5 to write up a dissertation. My source is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Svensson2012} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The bibliography is:

```
@article{Svensson2012,
    title = {{Intellectual property law compliance in Europe: Illegal file sharing and the role of social norms}},
    volume = {{14}},
    shorttitle = {{Intellectual property law compliance in Europe}},
    pages = {1147–1163},
    number = {7},
    journaltitle = {{New media \& society}},
    author = {Svensson, M\textbackslash{}a ans and Larsson, Stefan},
    date = {2012},
    }
}
```

The author's name is Måns in the original and the bibliography is automatically generated. It is the `\textbackslash` which is causing the problem. If I remove it the problem goes away.

When I run xelatex I hit the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \\bibnamedelima unavailable in encoding EU1.
```

I am using biber version 1.8. I am afraid I don't really understand font encodings and/or how they interact with biber in this way. I would appreciate help.

Comment: You shouldn't use T1-encoding with xelatex. Use `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead. Beside this: don't send code snippets. Always try to make a complete example other can try out.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead of T1 complains that `\bibnamedelima` is unavailable in encoding EU1, so that doesn't help. As for an example: what do I do? Since the problem appears to be in my bibliography, wouldn't I have to upload that as well? I can't locate the precise cause in the bibliography, so that could be rather long. Any ideas? I really don't understand what is going on here, so any light shed would be useful.

Comment: Test if you get the error delete the bbl and if you put only `\bibnamedelima` in your document. If yes the bib is not relevant and something in your preamble is the problem.

Comment: I've produced a minimal complete example. Hopefully what I am doing wrong will be clearer now.

Comment: The `\textbackslash` is of course wrong. You have to fix it to be `M\aa ns`; probably the automatic generator is not very smart. Since you're using Biber, also `Måns` would be good.

Comment: Thanks. The automatic generator wasn't to blame in fact, the original source somehow had M\a ans in it. Putting Måns in the original makes everything work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Svensson2012,
    title = {Intellectual property law compliance in Europe: Illegal file sharing and the role of social norms},
    volume = {14},
    shorttitle = {Intellectual property law compliance in Europe},
    pages = {1147–1163},
    number = {7},
    journaltitle = {New media \& society},
    author = {Svensson, M\TBS a ans and Larsson, Stefan},
    date = {2012},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\let\TBS\textbackslash
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

foo~\cite{Svensson2012} 
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However, `\a` makes no sense in the output!